# Overwrite method or derive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

For a given class, is it better/fancier/more in accordance with Python Zen to overwrite a method (I.e., assign another function to it) or derive from that class and overwrite it in the new class.

So this:

```
from foo import Bar
def mybaz(self):
    pass
Bar.baz = mybaz
```

Or:

```
from foo import bar
class Mybar(Bar):
    def baz(self):
        pass
```

If it makes a difference, please refer to Python3

Follow up: is the answer different for magic methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second way is more preferable as it doesn't change the base class, but extends it, take a look at the [open/closed principle.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)